# What are these droops in the drywall?

Tags: drywall

There's a few droopy-looking sections of drywall where the ceiling meets the wall (see album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsOG1.jpg) that have existed since I bought the house more than a year ago and haven't gotten any worse in that period of time.

My home inspector never said anything about them and they don't feel soft/soggy or cool to the touch (which I assume water damage would feel like one or all of these things). So what could be the reason for the droops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its hard to view the pictures on my phone, but two possibilities I can see:

The ceiling drywall may be unsupported at the edge.  Usually you put the ceiling up first, so the wall drywall supports the edges of it.  You can't do this (easily) if at some point only the ceiling was repaired.  This could make it flex down a bit between the joists it is screwed to.

Poor taping and mudding.  Between sheets of drywall you use tape (basically strips of paper) and mud to smooth out the edges.  Some of those look like the tape started to pull away from the ceiling before the mud hardened.

If it hasn't changed, its nothing to worry about - just a cosmetic annoyance.

Edit:  Looking closer from a computer, I'm almost certain that's just a poor taping job.  You can clearly see the inch or so line across the seam where the tape is.

Comment: I agree.  But even during a repair you can set the ceiling on top of wall.

Comment: @DMoore sure, you can.  But I have seen many lazy people not do it (because they didn't feel like actually getting the drywall scraps and screws out from above the wall drywall).  It certainly isn't as easy as when doing it from scratch.

Comment: It also looks like too much mud built up in the tapered joints, which causes mounding. You can see it clearer where you have a straight line, such as a wall/ceiling corner.